# What is --data-dir=${PWD} in my tutorial instructions?

Tags: command-line, python

I am following instructions in a tutorial.

Download the CIFAR-10 dataset and generate TFRecord files using the provided script. The script and associated command below will download the CIFAR-10 dataset and then generate a TFRecord for the training, validation, and evaluation datasets.

The command that I am supposed to run is:

`python generate_cifar10_tfrecords.py --data-dir=${PWD}/cifar-10-data`

For the `{PWD}` portion am I supposed to keep it `{PWD}` or am I supposed to change it to a working directory of my choosing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `${PWD}` is a variable substitution of the shell and instructs the shell to insert, instead of this string, the value of the "environment variable" `PWD` which is always the absolute path of the directory you are currently in and therefore contains the same string you get when running

```
user@host$ pwd
```

on the command-line.

If your data is (to be) located in a sub-directory `cifar-10-data` under the directory you are running the command from, you can keep it literally. If not, you should instead replace it with the path to the data you want to apply your script to (or the path you want the data to be downloaded to; you should find the exact meaning of the path in the documentation of the script).

In principle, prepending a path with `${PWD}/` should not be necessary unless the command you are invoking requires absolute pathnames (which, of course, may be true in your case).